# Fluent Validation on nested class members

Tags: c#, nested, fluentvalidation

I have a budgeting app that allows budgets to have N-tier sub budgets. The Class in question is `LineItem`:

```
class LineItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Guid Id{ get; set; }
        public ICollection<LineItem> Children = new HashSet<LineItem>();
        public virtual IDictionary<string, double> Budgets {get; set;}          
    }
```

I'm trying to create a Fluent Validator for this class with the following rules in mind:

1. It is N-Tier... I need to be able to check at every level.
2. I need to know at what level (by ID?) the validation failed.
3. Validations need to trickle up.
4. A null Budget means unlimited... This makes things complicated.

So, for a valid / complex budget example:

```
validParent (food budget=100)
├── child1 (unlimited food budget)
│   ├── grandchild1 (food budget=15)
│   ├── grandchild2 (food budget=10)
└── child2 (food budget=75)
```

and here that same structure that is invalid:

```
validParent (food budget=100)
├── child1 (unlimited food budget)
│   ├── grandchild1 (food budget=15)
│   ├── grandchild2 (food budget=70) <- sum of the children on this branch is too much!
└── child2 (food budget=75) <- not enough left!
```

I have a validator that works at any level with it's child, but only its direct child:

```
public class BudgetValidator : AbstractValidator<LineItem>
{
    public BudgetValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(evtNode => evtNode.Budgets).Custom((budgets, context) =>
        {
            LineItem parent = context.InstanceToValidate as LineItem;

            if (parent.Budgets != null) // check if this level is null. if it is, it is valid.
            {
                IDictionary<string, double> childBudgets = parent.Children.SelectMany(d => d.Budgets).GroupBy(
                       dict => dict.Key,
                       dict =>
                       {
                           if (parent.Budgets.ContainsKey(dict.Key) && parent.Budgets[dict.Key] < dict.Value)
                           {
                               context.AddFailure($"Invalid child budget ({dict.Key}). Child budget must not exceed that of parent.");
                           }
                           return dict.Value;
                       },
                       (key, g) => new { Key = key, Value = g.Sum() }
                   ).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);

                foreach (var budget in childBudgets)
                {
                    if (parent.Budgets.ContainsKey(budget.Key))
                    {
                        if (parent.Budgets[budget.Key] < budget.Value)
                        {
                            context.AddFailure($"Invalid budget. Sum of Budgets ({budget.Key}) must not exceed that of parent.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        RuleForEach(evtNode => evtNode.Children).SetValidator(this);
    }
```

**How can I account for when a level has an "unlimited budget"?** It's children would treat it as "unlimited" but the parent would need to know if the grandchildren exceeded the limit.

Here is a dotnet fiddle with the class
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nkc4ob

Comment: Would it make it easier if each level had an additional property that tracked whether *its* budget had been violated? But your invalid example is confusing though - because does that child really have an unlimited budget, or is it only 25? the sum of the children *doesn't* exceed 'unlimited', so why is that considered invalid? It sounds like you should have further cascading rules that prevent unlimited budgets below a limited budget.